# Question about $p(A),$ where $p$ is a polynomial and $A$ a matrix.

Tags: abstract-algebra

In Dummit & Foote the following are given as the first two steps toward converting an $n\times n$ matrix into rational canonical form:

[image: Dummit & Foote Page 482]

My question is about step 2 part (b). If $p(x)=c$ constant then is $p(A)$ just the $n \times n$ matrix whose entries are all $c$'s?

Answer (score 1):

For a polynomial $P(x)=a_nx^n+..+a_1x+a_0$, and a matrix $A$, $P(A)$ is defined as
$$
P(A):=a_nA^n+..+a_1A+a_0I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

In particular, if $P=c$ is the constant polynomial, $P(A)=cI$.

Comment: Thanks! I almost messed it up! Haha